# Words to exclude from a search

Tags: list, search, words, false-positive

I am looking for a list of words that I can use as exclusions from a product search, as they will give to many false positives.

This would include things like 'a', 'with', 'and', 'the' and so forth.  Does anyone have or know where I could download a list of these types of words?  The list would only need to be in English (British if possible).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is called stopword list. They are available for different languages for example at https://github.com/Alir3z4/stop-words

Comment: Brilliant didn't know the word to search for to get results (ironically) so thanks for telling me what to search for next time